# Progress4gl - list the items in unix system similar to combo-box in windows

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

In progress4gl, is there any way to list the items without using the dropdown/combo-box such that it supports unix also.. Is there any alternative progress4gl command for combo-box.

Answer (score 1):

The combo-box works in Unix, at least in character (tty/terminal) mode.

Consider this simple example and the "VIEW-AS phrase":

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cVar AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO FORMAT "x(10)" LABEL "Choose!"
    VIEW-AS COMBO-BOX 
    INNER-LINES 5 LIST-ITEMS "Item A","Item B","Item C","Item D","Item E","Item F".

UPDATE cVar.
```

This will work on Windows and produce a drop down. And also on Unix/Linux (pressing down will expand the selections - pressing enter will select).

However if you want to create a graphical mouse supported gui for Unix/Linux (X, KDE/Gnome etc) you're out of luck - that is not supported.

[image: Linux terminal Image][image: Windows GUI Image]